# Flutter: GetX - How navigate to different Views with same Controller class using Get.toNamed()?

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-getx

I am trying to implement GetX navigation within the below code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      getPages: [
        GetPage(name: '/', page: () => HomeScreen()),
        GetPage(name: '/second', page: () => SecondScreen())
      ],
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => Get.toNamed('/second', arguments: 'A'),
              child: Text('Second Screen A')),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => Get.toNamed('/second', arguments: 'B'),
              child: Text('Second Screen B'))
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var controller =
        Get.put(SecondScreenController(), tag: Get.arguments);
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text(controller.text),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => Get.toNamed('/second',
                  arguments: controller.text == 'A' ? 'B' : 'A'),
              child: controller.text == 'A'
                  ? Text('Switch to other second screen B')
                  : Text('Switch to other second screen A'))
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}

class SecondScreenController extends GetxController {
  final text = Get.arguments;
}
```

Navigation from the `HomeScreen` to `SecondScreen` works totally fine. Only when I am in `SecondScreen` I cannot navigate to the same screen again filling it with **different** `arguments` (`'B'` or `'A'`) contained within the **same** controller class. I tried to use the `tag` property when *putting* the Controller as specified [here](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/dependency_management.md#getput), but it does not help. My guess is that my `SecondScreen` simply does not rebuild as Flutter regards it (or the attached `controller`) as existing already. How can I specify a `tag` within the routing method `Get.toNamed()` in order to tell Flutter that `SecondScreen` needs to rebuild?

Maybe I am doing things completely wrong and what I would like to achieve is actually done differently. I am happy for any advice and help!

Answer (score 2):

just add property `preventDuplicates = false` inner `Get.toNamed(widget.path, preventDuplicates = false)` and dont forget use Get.create as injection to take fresh-controller for you UI(Widget)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have a strange navigation behavior that to navigate same screen (/seconds -> /seconds) again. But if you insist want to do that, by default Getx will prevent you to push same route that you already in. If you want to push anyway, set [preventDuplicates] to false

```
Get.toNamed('/second', arguments: controller.text == 'A' ? 'B' : 'A', preventDuplicates = false);
```

By the way, you may also consider to use [Getx dynamic URLs](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/route_management.md#dynamic-urls-links) to achieve your use case.

```
Map<String, String> parameters = {
  'argument': 'A',
};
Get.toNamed('/second', arguments: controller.text == 'A' ? 'B' : 'A', preventDuplicates: false, parameters: parameters);

// To retrieve the parameter in your next screen's controller
final String argument = Get.parameters['argument']!;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that by doing

```
 var controller = Get.put(SecondScreenController(), tag: Get.arguments);
```

you are putting a new instance of the SecondScreenController() everytime, therefore the parameters you're sending will not be set.
Try doing   `Get.lazyPut(() => SecondScreenController());` somewhere outside this logic (maybe when initializing the app), then do `var controller = Get.find<SecondScreenController>()` to always get the same instance.

Or even better!

```
class SecondScreen extends GetView<SecondScreenController> {}
```

and inside this class you will be able to use the `controller` variable(Already defined in the GetView, which represents the controller declared between <>) without doing any assignment.